# limits ocurrence in a select

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I wanna to do a select that It return me a group of objects that they have a same data. My problem are this: I have select

```
select * 
from avi
where codAvi in (select codAVi 
                 from csa 
                 where codEca in (select codEca 
                                  from csa 
                                  where codAvi =19));
```

My problem are if i codAvi 19 have codEca 1,2,3 that query return all avi with that codEca and he return others for example avi with codEca 1,2,3,4.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At finally I use that:

```
SELECT * FROM avi where codAvi in (SELECT e.codAVi FROM csa e WHERE e.codEca IN (SELECT c.codEca FROM csa C WHERE  c.codAvi = 19) GROUP BY e.codAvi HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM csa a WHERE a.codAvi  = 19))
```

Comment: I search all avi that have same codEca that avi that I pass.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what data you actually want.  Some example data and what you expect the output to be would help.

Here is your query using joins, maybe this makes the logic clearer for you?

```
select * 
from avi
join csa as csa1 on avi.codAvi = csa1.codAvi
join csa as cas2 on csa1.codEca = csa2.codEca
where csa2.codAvi = 19
```

Answer (score 2):

The innermost query returns all CSA rows where codAvi = 19 (presumably, 2,3,4).

The "middle" query returns the codAVI value of all CSA rows where codECA is in that first result set. If that's 2,3,4, then you get all the codAVIs that relate to at least one of these codEca values, and here that's presumably 1,2,3,4 (perhaps codEca of 2 is referenced by both codAVI 2 and codAVI 1?)

And thus, the outermost query could return data from table AVI for 1,2,3,4, even though 1 has no reference to codAvi 19.

---

Here's some sample data that fits the situation I see:

```
CSA
codAvi  CodEca
  1       2
  7       7
 19       2
 19       3
 19       4


AVI
codAVI
  1
  7
 19
```